# What if our hearts didn’t pulse?

Tags: heart, heart-rate, heartbeat

Let’s say we used an electric pump that’s smart enough to adjust the blood flow according to the needs of the body.

What would be the effects on our organs?
Would we survive without the beats?

I just recently read that scientists at the Texas Heart Institute developed a bionic heard that works within this principle, but I’d like to know the medical/scientific implications of getting rid of the beats.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Regarding my comment above, I recommend you begin by googling the acronym LVAD. Hearts that don't create a pulse are not a new thing.